# Best way to pass control to parent/base class in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an abstract BasePage class that each Page class inherits from. Apart from core functionality I'd like BasePage to cover repetitive tasks that almost all derived classes implement. To do this however the BasePage class would have to hold reference to controls (dropdownlist, gridview, menu...) which are defined in derived class.

My question is what is the best way to pass control reference defined in derived Page class to parent class?

None of the following really gives "best" solution:

1. Base page to declare variable with name that is the same as control's Id on derived class. This forces the ASP.NET designer not to re-create the control on derived class. (I don't like this since derived class is forced to know and use hard-coded name)
2. Create abstract property and force derived class to return control reference (CON: In some cases derived class might not include such control)
3. Pass the control as function call parameter (CON: still requires repetitive code of function call. Function itself then doesn't even have to be on BasePage)

Answer (score 3):

A more object oriented approach would be to extend the control classes (dropdownlist, gridview, menu...) and add methods for your repetitive tasks.

If you must define the controls in your BasePage, then you could create a [virtual property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for these in BasePage. Any derived page that wants to use it would override this and provide the required control.

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected virtual DropDownList MyDropDown { get; set; }

    protected void PopulateList()
    {
        if (MyDropDown != null)
            MyDropDown.Items.Add("option");
    }
}

public partial class MyPage : BasePage
{
    protected override DropDownList MyDropDown
    {
        get
        {
            return DerivedClassList;
        }
        set
        {
            base.DerivedClassList = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An abstract class/property would probably be even better.

Comment: That would force him to implement the property, and as he mentioned in his solution 2, not all of his derived classes have all the abstract controls. A virtual property here serves to provide a default implementation(null).

Comment: Sorry, I should have read the question better.  Looking at it more closely, however, I think the base class property only needs a getter and not the setter as well.

Comment: I see the point of extending the controls though in my case the functionality really belongs to the Page class (as it might include business objects)

Comment: The virtual property seems to be the best compromise so far, the issues I experience with it is that it repeats a lot on pages plus developers sometime "forget" to override one or two properties which then affects the functionality that could go unnoticed... so it is "chicken and the egg" question